# Making text bold on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am thinking of making some kind of browser based addon, maybe for chrome which makes the text bold between quote marks. I was wondering, is this possible to do and what would I need to research to be able to do it?

Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of words like thinking of and maybe. I think you should think of what you want to do and ask again when you do know.

Comment: I want to make an addon for a browser that makes text bold between the quotes. Is this possible and what do i need to research?

Comment: I beleve this is possible by injecting JS code into each page that is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

First: Yes it is possible.

Take a look at how to develop [Chrome Extensions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html) and [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html). For this problem I think Content Scripts should be the solution you are looking for.

To turn text bold simply look into [RegExp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) to find quotes in HTML text (not the whole HTML!) and text contained within them and then just wrap it around in strong tags.
To find the text you could extract text with help of [jQuery .text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

Simple mock-up for replace script would be:
`$(body).text().replace(/"([^"]*)"/mg, '"<strong>$1</strong>"')`

You can build on this sample, if you decide to..
Though you still have to be careful not to replace any text inside script tags.

Though for this simple script you do without extension but simple [user script](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts). I don't think there is a need for extension..

Comment: A UserScript is converted to an extension. Parsing HTML with a RegEx is a bad idea.

Comment: @RobW Well UserScript is converted, but from developer (code writer perspective) it is easier to write, no need for manifest file and other needed files for chrome extensions, just simple JS file and that is all.
And why would RegEx be bad idea? Quote finding could be a little tricky, but I didn't mean to simply wrap all quotes in HTML with strong tags.. I will fix my answer

Comment: The suggested method destroys the lay-out, because `.text()` returns the text *0without HTML tags*. Even when `.text()` is changed to `.html()`, `<a href="x"></a>` will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a chrome extension, here is where you need to go to get started:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devguide.html

Answer (score 0):

The most complicated part is probably how to define what you would treat as quote marks and how you would recognize them. There are dozens of different quotes used, in different ways, so that, for example, the right-pointing double angle quotation mark (») is an opening quote in some languages, a closing quote in some other languages, and both opening and closing in a few languages. Moreover, this character is often used as not indicating a quote of any kind but as an arrow-like symbol.

I don’t know why you would bold text between quotes, but if it is for highlighting of some kind, then using a distinctive background color might work better. Bolding may increase the width requirements of text, usually not much, but many web pages have pixel-exact layout that might crumble into pieces if words get a few pixels wider.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".boldAllQuotationMarks").each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/"([^"]*)"/mg, '"<strong style="color:#333">$1</strong>"'));
    });
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why it works. Also, is it possible to break that second line so it doesn't scroll horizontally?

Comment: I don't understand you ? 

Can you explain?